# Is the output of a 12V DC driver different depending on forward or reverse phase AC input?

Tags: led, led-driver, led-strip, lighting

Does the output of a 120 volt AC to 12 volt DC LED driver differ depending on whether it receives forward-phase AC input or reverse-phase AC input from a dimmer?

I’m curious because I have some LED lamps that are failing prematurely and some that are not.

The ones that seem happier are those that came with a [universal driver](https://www.armacostlighting.com/products/12v-dimmable-led-driver) that’s advertised as accepting either forward or reverse phase, but [preferring **forward-phase**](https://web.archive.org/web/20220810182657/https://www.armacostlighting.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Armacost_Lighting-Universal-Dimming-Drivers-DataSheet.pdf).

The ones failing prematurely (of course, the much more $$$ ones) came with a [universal driver](https://emcod.com/products/info?id=464&) that’s advertised as accepting either forward or reverse phase, but preferring **reverse-phase**.

Definition of [forward-phase and reverse-phase linked here](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/Dimmer-Forward-and-Reverse-Application-Note.pdf).

Any ideas about why the DC output of the LED driver depends on the AC phased input? Should the AC signal not be rectified and thus the same?

Comment: Depends on the LED driver. Most will be happy with either but the devil is in the details. Check the datasheet.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question: the ones that say prefer forward-phase prefer forward-phase, and the others don't. I presume the dimmer is forward-phase.

Comment: Do you know why the output of an LED driver is different depending on the input being reverse or forward phase? That’s what I’m after. I wonder why the output isn’t the same DC voltage signal.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that forward phase dimming might cause higher stress because of the fast rise time where voltage is suddenly applied, whereas reverse phase applies power at zero crossing. It might help to add an inductor to reduce the dV/dt of the forward phase waveform.

Comment: Thanks for the definition link! I’ve merged it into the question.

Comment: “reduce the dV/dt of the forward phase waveform” – interesting! How could I measure this? Why would the voltage change if it’s being rectified (presumably) by the LED driver? Maybe that’s a misplaced assumption on my part?

Comment: @EdwardOcampo-Gooding If you turn on the voltage at the zero crossing it charges the power supply capacitors gradually.  If you turn on at full power much higher peak current rushes into the power supply to charge up the capacitors.